# Multiple AJAX calls in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I need a way to send multiple AJAX calls at the same time in Javascript/Angular.
After some searching i couldn't find an answer.
What i want to do is send all my requests as fast as possible.
If i execute my calls in a for loop or in a queue of promises with the $q library in Angular, a request gets sent, waits for it to execute the callback, and then sends the next one.
This is a example code:

```
var array = [];
    Page.get({id:1}, function(result){
        for(var i = 0; i < result.region[0].hotspots.length; i++){
            var promise = Hotspot.get({id: result.region[0].hotspots[i].id});
            array.push(promise);
        }
        $q.all(array).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Page is a angular resource with a get method which requires a ID.

What i want is that they all get sent at the same time and they call their callback when ready. The order in which the calls get returned doesn't really matter.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `XMLHttpRequest` in `JavaScript` to send all the request server without any callback and callback function called only when request is completed. I implement the `XMLHttpRequest` in HTML I does not how We will implement in the `angularjs`.

Comment: If the second request not gets sent before the first has finished, it seems, someone uses synchronous mode. Normally (in async mode) you'll return immediately from req.send() and are able to send the next one.

Comment: Well yes. Thats my confusion and only use async calls with Angular resource...

Answer (score 1):

### Think outside the box with Web Workers

An interesting aproach to solve this question, is to use **web workers** to execute the requests in a **different thread**. if you are not familiar with web workers i advice you to start by this [**great tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMK-jcOAYI8) of [**techsith**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbGZKLIHpox2l0whz6_RYyg). Basically, you will be able to execute multiple jobs at the same time. See also the [**W3Schools Documentation**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp).

[image]

This [**article**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers) from [**Html5Rocks**](http://www.html5rocks.com/) teach us how to use Web Workers without a separate script file.

Comment: Interesting idea. Since they're on a separate thread anyway, you can write the laziest, `async=false` code you like. Do any of the browsers skip their syncronicity warning when you do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that i understood your doubt, but this is similar to the background scripts in chrome extensions, they work as a "new window". I believe that you have the same limitations of syncronisity but in a different thread.. Anyway, check the browser compability and start the experiments! http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. There was no "doubt", I'm just interested. The only question I had is that most browsers will throw a warning in the dev console if you ever use XHR with async: false. Ideally, that warning won't appear if the call is made in a web worker, because the arguments against it no longer apply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachcoll-iteratee-callback) module?

You can achieve desired behavior using something like

```
Page.get({id:1}, function(result){
    async.each(result.region[0].hotspots, callAsync, function(err, res){
        console.log(res);
    }
});

function callAsync(hotspot, callback){
    callback(null, Hotspot.get({id: hotspot.id});
}
```

From Doc :

> **each(coll, iteratee, [callback])**
>
> Applies the function iteratee to each item in coll, in parallel. The
>   iteratee is called with an item from the list, and a callback for when
>   it has finished. If the iteratee passes an error to its callback, the
>   main callback (for the each function) is immediately called with the
>   error.

Answer (score 0):

The `$http` service sends XHRs in parallel. The code below demostrates 10 XHRs being sent to `httpbin.org` and subsequently being received in a different order.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myVm', function ($scope, $http) {
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.sentList = [];
    vm.rcvList = [];
    //XHR with delay from 9 to 1 seconds
    for (var n=9; n>0; n--) {
        var url = "https://httpbin.org/delay/" + n;
        vm.sentList.push(url);
        $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
             vm.rcvList.push(response.data.url);
        });
    };
    //XHR with 3 second delay
    var url = "https://httpbin.org/delay/3";
    vm.sentList.push(url);
    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
         vm.rcvList.push(response.data.url);
    })
})
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uv580a11/).